# How to fill a table cell to the end with vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

If I try to change it, its size is too limited

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(3, 2).Range = text + " " + String(200,".")
```

[image]

Comment: @FaneDuru - more than a certain length of points are not added

Comment: @FaneDuru: It's about Word, not Excel. But the question is unclear anyhow. But guess OP is looking for some tabulator settings to fill a cell.

Comment: @FunThomas Ups... I missed that. I will delete my comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Const Txt As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
With ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(3, 2)
  .Range.Text = Txt + " " + String(200, ".")
  .Range.FitTextWidth = .Width
End With
End Sub
```